# Android clipPath not working

Tags: android, android-canvas, clip

I am trying to clip paths in my imageview. But nothing is happening.

**My ImageView**

```
 public static class CliptImageView extends ImageView {
    Path path = new Path();

    public CliptImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CliptImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CliptImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        path.reset();
        float y = getMeasuredHeight() / 2.0f;
        float x = getMeasuredWidth() / 2.0f;
        path.addCircle(x,y, 20,Path.Direction.CW);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();

        canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

I add the imageview programatically to a linearLayout like this

```
      private View getMiddleArea() {
        CliptImageView imageView = new CliptImageView(getContext());


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.white));



//        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_bar_semicircle);
//        imageView.getBackground().setLevel(5000);
        return imageView;
    }
```

Nothing happens. The view is kept white. So i am obviously doing something wrong. But i have no idea what. I have had a lot of trial and error the latest 2 days. But nothing seems to work.

So any help that would get me in the right path is appreciated

**Edit update**

This is what i am trying to achieve. a transparent circle that clips the view and makes everything transparent

[image]

Comment: what API level are you running your app on? and what does `Canvas#isHardwareAccelerated` return?

Comment: MIN_SDK=16
COMPILE_SDK=25
TARGET_SDK=25
Hardwareacc = true

Comment: But i have tried to turn hardwareacceleration off. Still same result

Comment: ok and what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: added a image of what i am trying to achieve

Comment: i know. But i did it for testing. Because nothing happened when i added the correct circle.

Comment: your code `path.addCircle(x,y, 20,Path.Direction.CW);` adds only small circle with radius of 20 pixels, this is not what you want to get, but if its only test then override `draw(Canvas canvas)`, and not `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`

Comment: This only added a black circle. It did not make it transparent

Comment: ah it worked now when i turned the hardware acceleration on! :D